# Sending AVRCP play command, getting spammed with broadcast

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-intent, broadcast, avrcp

I have some hardware that sends the AVRCP play command to the phone
upon bluetooth connection. What I am seeing is the MEDIA_BUTTON action
intent spammed over and over in the debugger. This is causing problems
with a few apps but mainly Pandora. Pandora will constantly play/pause
over and over. It is almost like the AVRCP command gets sent to the
phone which generates a MEDIA_BUTTON broadcast that keeps getting sent
out over and over.

I set up a Broadcast Receiver to catch it and try to determine what's
going on. Here is what is being spammed:

> 01-17 12:20:04.324: ERROR/NPT:(1558):
>   Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON
>   (has extras) } 01-17 12:20:04.324:
>   ERROR/NPT:(1558): KeyEvent{action=0
>   code=85 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=200
>   mFlags=8}

which is the bluetooth Play/Pause media key. This is what it should
be, as the AVRCP command triggers this, but as I said, it's like the
OS just keeps spamming this.

I have tried using the `abortBroadcast()` method to stop it but that has
no effect. I am guessing the broadcast is non-ordered and can't be
stopped explicitly?

I have verified it is not the hardware spamming the AVRCP command by
debugging my firmware code. The spamming behavior also continues if I
unplug the hardware.

I am using 2.2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been resolved. Turns out it was a problem with the hardware. I was sending the AVRCP play button down command but never sending the button up command. The phone was basically seeing this as the play button being "held down" so it kept sending the broadcast.

Comment: Hi Bob, Could you please help me to send AVRCP commands to a device.